# Ember computed.sort fails after setting sortProperties multiple times

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to implement sorting + filtering into my array controller. Everything is working except my template doesn't seem to get the computed properties after a change the sort direction more than 2 times. Im not sure whats really going wrong or if its a bug.

Here is the relevant code and a [**failing bin**](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qoyim/5/edit)(click the sort button multiple times, the template stops showing the computed properties from the item controller).

```
{{#each sortedContent}}
  <li>{{title}} - {{symbol}}{{totalAmount}}</li>
{{/each}}

App.IndexController = Em.ArrayController.extend({

  itemController: 'item',

  filterText: '',

  sortProperties: ['totalAmount:asc'],
  sortedContent: Em.computed.sort('filteredContent', 'sortProperties'),

  filteredContent: function() {
    console.log('filter');
    return this.filter(function(item) {
      return item.get('title').indexOf(this.get('filterText')) >= 0;
    }.bind(this));
  }.property('filterText','@this'),

  actions: {
    sortBy: function() {
      var direction = 'asc';
      if(this.get('sortProperties.0').split(':')[1] === 'asc') {
        direction = 'desc'; 
      }
      console.log('totalAmount:'+direction);
      this.set('sortProperties', ['totalAmount:'+direction]);
    }
  }

});

App.ItemController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  totalAmount: Em.computed.alias('price.amount'),
  symbol: Em.computed.alias('price.currency')
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I totally think it's a bug, I'm not sure what piece of code to blame though...  I'd probably submit a bug

Comment: Hmmm... not so sure this is a bug. I think this has to do with the sort macro internals returning a new array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Ember, or something else, hates your item controller.  My working guess/theory is it disconnects from the item controller at some point, and then all of your sorting and other labels break (due to them being reliant on the item controller)

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jakax/1/edit

I'm not sure exactly what the issue is, but I'd probably just wrap it in a normal Ember Object (depending on what you're trying to do).

```
App.Foo = Em.Object.extend({
  totalAmount: Em.computed.alias('price.amount'),
  symbol: Em.computed.alias('price.currency')
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jakax/2/edit

Comment: I also got this working by filtering the sorted content. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qoyim/2/edit This seems like a bug to me. First condition wont work for me as my computed properties are a bit more complete in the actual use case. Anyway thanks for the alternate solutions. Will be helpful in other scenarios.

Comment: I went ahead and upvoted because I think this is a good alternative pattern, but this isn't the right answer. The problem was that the `sortProperties` weren't bound so the view was confused about what to render.

Comment: @matthew-blancarte kingpin2k Opened an issue https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/5239

Comment: I should have used different phrasing... "Right" is totally the wrong word here haha! I should have said that I was able to get your pattern working.

Answer (score 4):

Took me a while of staring at it, but I knew it was something small.

Your sorted content and filtered content are both computed, so you need to make sure they are both watching each other for changes. If you bind `sortProperties` to `filteredContent`, it will work.

```
property('filterText', '@this', 'sortProperties')
```

Working JSBin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bicepobu/1/edit

I realized that the collection was still alive and no errors were being thrown when I started entering filters into the text field and it was rendering, then I could click twice and bug it out again...

Computed property errors are pretty much the equivalent of the old "forgotten semi-colon". I swear that 9/10 bugs in my own Ember code are from this sort of thing.

**Update::**

Okay, so I think I can better describe what's happening. You are feeding in the `filteredContent` to the macro. That macro is removing and adding items to your filtered content array. If you think about it, what's happening makes sense.

Take a look at this line: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.6.1/packages_es6/ember-runtime/lib/computed/reduce_computed_macros.js#L756

```
return arrayComputed(itemsKey, { //...
```

1. You hit the button to run the sort macro.
2. The sort macro rips apart and reconstructs the `filteredContent`, **returning a new collection**. This is where `filteredContent` loses sight!
3. When you hit the filter button **the second time**, it's trying to access the original `filteredContent`, which was ripped apart and was never updated with the new model! (thus, the need to watch `sortedProperties` for changes). It worked the first time because it had a healthy origin array to work from. The second time, it was grabbing at "thin air" (empty array).

If your custom filter property isn't watching for changes to sortProperties, it doesn't know to re-establish itself after being mangled in the macro.

Yikes! Certainly don't hold it against the Ember guys.

It would be nice if the sort macro just returned the same collection and not a brand new one... There is probably a really good reason for this.

Comment: With this solution, filteredContent triggers everytime I want to sort. My idea is that, sorting is not adding/removing any items, it just reorders. So the sortedContent should just listen to the sortProperties and sort the filteredContent. filteredContent should only execute if the filterText or arraycontroller item changes.

Comment: My actual use case is that I am applying multiple filters to a single list. So the filter function is one big function which executes a set of filter functions on a the list item. I just thought it would perform better if it didnt execute the filter function when a user changed the sort order or property. Makes sense?

Comment: Still weird to me.  filtered doesn't depend on the sorted content and can live without it (http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bicepobu/2/edit) and keeps working.  Making it depend on the `sortProperties` causes it to trigger a new set of item controllers each time, which does work, but shouldn't be necessary... http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bicepobu/3/edit crazy stuff

Comment: @blessenm Indeed, this will fire ever time you want to sort.

Comment: @kingpin2k I was looking at the sort macro internals and it is completely ripping apart the array and reconstructing it. All those items are technically new array items after the sort, so ember needs to re-init the entire collection to keep things bound. Crazy stuff!

Comment: Hmm interesting stuff. I gave up trying to understand the internals. Too complex for me. From what I see, the macro isn't reconstructing properly which i think is a bug. If you have any more information or comment please add them to the github issue. I guess it will help the core team or at least give them more reason to further inspect.